# How to Make My score Board works

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have been trying to make a score board, which will start counting from when the helicopter start running till when it falls cause of crashing with a enemie, but the score is not running or doing anything would you tell me whats the problem of my code?

http://prntscr.com/2aospf

that is the game, which is in frame 3, my button of play on frame 2 and the pre loader on frame 1

```
var score:"0";
//scoreCounter is the instance name of the dynamic text box

    function updateScore():void{
     score += 1;
     scoreCounter.text = score.toString();
}
```

what im doing wrong? it doesnt start counting when the helicopter runs, thanks.

Comment: Put some debug in updateScore and see if it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your function whenever the score has to update? If the objective is to purely not hit an enemy and the score therefore based on time, you should call the function at the start of the frame and put a while loop around the counting and updating of the scoreCounter within the function to make the score go up through time.

Comment: addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction); -> with myFunction being your function name. Put that along the top of your code. I'd suggest using a for-loop since you can then easily set the maximum score of your game and add a pause of a certain amount of milliseconds in between every count. That should get you a long way